# Minimize HTML into a single line

Tags: html, compression

I need to minimize this code to a single line.

I am using Adobe Edge and am creating some code for some paragraphs inside one text box. If your interested the code needs to be loaded into an area called `document.compositionReady`.

The big limitation is that the way the code is loaded through javascript does not allow for multiple lines to be used.

So I have already done this manually and its not a problem, it works fine but it takes a long time. I can use Aptana studio with the `format` command to un-compress the code back to normal, the problem is that during development I am constantly having to compress this code into a single line manually, which is time consuming and distracting.

So I need a manual tool that can turn this:

```
<style media='screen' type='text/css'>
    .text {
        padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
</style>

<!-- now for html -->

<div style='width:550px;' >
    <div style='float:left;font-size:1.2em;' class='text'>
        Title goes here
    </div>
    <div style='width:60px;float:left;' class='text'>
        <span style='font-size:0.8em;'>
            ®
        </span>
    </div>
    <div style='float:left' class='text'>
        Some paragraph text
    </div>
    <div style='float:left;padding-top:10px;' class='text'>
        <span style='font-style:italic;'>
            A footer to the paragraph
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

into this:

```
<style media='screen' type='text/css'>.text {padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;font-size:12px;}</style><!-- now for html --><div style='width:550px;' >  <div style='float:left;font-size:1.2em;' class='text'>MY BRILLIANCE</div><div style='width:60px;float:left;' class='text'>      <span style='font-size:0.8em;'>®</span> </div>  <div style='float:left' class='text'>       With release comes growth, through challenge comes wisdom, let us show you the way. </div>  <div style='float:left;padding-top:10px;' class='text'><span style='font-style:italic;'>Absolute Equal Acceptance through Thought, Conscience and Reunion.</span></div></div>
```

Comment: http://www.textfixer.com/html/compress-html-compression.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, google could be your friend.

http://www.textfixer.com/html/compress-html-compression.php

```
<style media='screen' type='text/css'>
    .text {
        padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
</style>

<!-- now for html -->

<div style='width:550px;' >
    <div style='float:left;font-size:1.2em;' class='text'>
        Title goes here
    </div>
    <div style='width:60px;float:left;' class='text'>
        <span style='font-size:0.8em;'>
            ®
        </span>
    </div>
    <div style='float:left' class='text'>
        Some paragraph text
    </div>
    <div style='float:left;padding-top:10px;' class='text'>
        <span style='font-style:italic;'>
            A footer to the paragraph
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

becomes

```
<style media='screen' type='text/css'> .text { padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px; font-size: 12px; }</style><!-- now for html --><div style='width:550px;' > <div style='float:left;font-size:1.2em;' class='text'> Title goes here </div> <div style='width:60px;float:left;' class='text'> <span style='font-size:0.8em;'> ® </span> </div> <div style='float:left' class='text'> Some paragraph text </div> <div style='float:left;padding-top:10px;' class='text'> <span style='font-style:italic;'> A footer to the paragraph </span> </div></div>
```

Or, if you want to compress on your desktop directly, you could use software like [Alentum](http://www.alentum.com/), [HTML Compressor](http://html-compressor.en.softonic.com/) etc...

Comment: Thanks! I did try a google search but came up with a few solutions but nothing that compressed to a single line. Cheers dude. my google-fu must be rubbish!

Answer (score -1):

something like `str_replace("\n", "", $text_to_be_compressed)`?

Comment: This is also terrible because, within HTML text elements, newlines are interpreted as whitespace, which means that, if I have two words separated by only a newline between a <p> and </p> tag, your replacement will turn what would otherwise be rendered as "find therapist" into "findtherapist". So you actually need to parse the HTML. That's one of the reasons HTML compression tools tend to be longer than one line of code. Unless OP is fine with lossy compression, in which case something like "replace_regex("*","",$text_to_be_compressed)" would be the optimal solution.